# Stress Testing to Improve Run Time

Tags: c++, time, stress-testing

I am taking an open course on Data Structures and Algorithms to get to know C++ a little better.

Basically the code takes the two highest inputs and then multiplies them together. The code that's provided takes a long time to run. They want us to use a stress test to locate and fix the bug in the program and I do not know where to start.

Here is the code that was provided:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int MaxPairwiseProduct(const vector<int>& numbers) {
int result = 0;
double n = numbers.size();   
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {  
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) { 
        if (numbers[i] * numbers[j] > result) { 
            result = numbers[i] * numbers[j];
        }
    }
}
return result;
}
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> numbers(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }

    int result = MaxPairwiseProduct(numbers);
    cout << result << "\n";
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `double n = numbers.size();`  Why are you storing the return value of `size()` in a `double`?  Second, your loop is `O(n*n)` -- imagine if there are 1000 numbers -- you will loop a million times.

Comment: A stress test would imply running the provided function thousands of times with different sized input, timing how long each run takes, and analyzing the results.  That seems to me like a good place to start.

Comment: Have they said anything about stress tests in the course, or do they just assume that everyone knows what it is? From just looking at the code I'd say that the currently used algorithm is the "bug". How would you do if you manually (e.g. pen and paper) want to find two numbers in a list numbers for which the product is greatest? Hint: you only need to go through the vector once and remember two things.

Comment: Also, make sure you build your program with optimizations turned on.   This is especially the case with Visual Studio, as vector in debug mode is notoriously slow due to iterator checking.

Comment: 1) do an optimized build. 2) use a profiler ('perf' is nice on Linux). 3) heed compiler warnings related to performance (and make sure you turn up/on warnings). 4) run a tool like 'clang tidy' and pay attention to its performance related checks/warnings.